# /i Command In Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I need help about the /i command. How can I get the lore in two lines?
I know that you can add attributes and use a command block, but my bucket doesn't accept JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /i command works like the give command but you don't need to specify a name of a player. Here is how you would give an item with a certain lore:

```
/i itemname 1 Lore:LOREGOESHERE (For Lore)
/i itemname 1 name:NAME GOES HERE (For Name)
/i itemname 1 lore:LORE name:NAME (For Both)
```

You can find more information [HERE](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Item_Meta)

NOTE: /i cannot be used in a command block, it will say only in-game players can use /i.

Hope I helped,

-Nick